# How can I show that $ \lim_{R\to+\infty}{\int_0^\pi\log(1-e^{2i(iR+x)})dx}=0 $?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that
$$
\lim_{R\to+\infty}{\int_0^\pi\log(1-e^{2i(iR+x)})dx}=0\quad ?
$$
What I've done so far is rewriting the integrand as
$$
\log(1-e^{2i(iR+x)})=\log|1-e^{2i(iR+x)}|+i\theta(x)
$$
It's not hard to get an estimate of $\log|1-e^{2i(iR+x)}|$.

> How can I estimate $|\log(1-e^{2i(iR+x)})|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Taylor series, it is easy to see that
$$
|\log(1-z)|\leq|\log(1-|z|)|
$$
for $|z|<1$.

So your integral is bounded by
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|\log(1-e^{-2R})|dx=2\pi |\log(1-e^{-2R})|.
$$

Now let $R$ tend to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{2i(iR+x)}=e^{-2R+2xi}=e^{-2R}(\cos 2x+i\sin 2x)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\left|1-e^{2i(iR+x)}\right|=\left|(1-e^{-2R}\cos 2x)+ie^{-2R}\sin 2x\right|=\sqrt{1+e^{-4R}-2e^{-2R}\cos 2x}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\log\left|1-e^{2i(iR+x)}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\log \left(1+e^{-4R}-2e^{-2R}\cos 2x\right)\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{2}\log 1=0$$